# Adding Table of contents to Sharpoint Wiki

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, wiki, sitepages, embedded

I'm trying to add a table of contents to a sharepoint wiki page, I've found coding online through forums but if i try to add imbedded code it doesnt work for some reason

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Embed web part won't accept the script. You can embed content from some websites by copying and pasting the site's web address for the content into the Embed web part.

To add the custom script, either

- we have to develop our own SPFX web part or
- Or use Page Navigator web part from Pnp Samples,  https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-page-navigator
- use the React Script Editor web part from PnP samples and add the custom javascript
  https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor

Hope this helps.

Comment: thankyou for the help, can you reccomend any walkthroughs/resources to do this? i have absolutely 0 expereince in coding/javascript/etc.